# If $m_{\alpha \beta}=-m_{\beta \alpha}$ do we have $m^{\alpha \beta}=-m^{\beta \alpha}$?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

My question might seems obvious but in fact I wrote in my course that:

$$m_{\alpha \beta}=-m_{\beta \alpha}$$ is equivalent to $$m^{\alpha \beta}=-m^{\beta \alpha}. \tag{*}$$

But I don't understand why.

First question:

Do you agree with me if I say that if I lower or put up a given indice $\mu$ to a side of an equation I have to lower or put up it on the other side of the equation and the resulting equation will be true?

For example: $A^{\alpha \beta \mu}=B^{\beta \alpha \mu} \Leftrightarrow A_{\alpha}^{. ~\beta \mu}=A_{. ~ \alpha ~ . }^{\beta ~ . ~ \mu}$

To prove it we just have to insert $\eta$ matrices at both side of the equation.

So why did I wrote (*)?

In fact I am almost sure that I made a mistake when I wrote it but the manipulation of indices is too important to not have a confirmation.

Comment: Yes, it's true, for precisely the reason that you state.

Answer (score 3):

Raising and lowering of indices is done with the metric tensor, i.e.
$$g_{\gamma\alpha}A^{\alpha\beta\mu} = A_{\gamma}^{\ \ \beta\mu}$$
Or in context of a full equation,
$$\begin{align}
A^{\alpha\beta\mu} &= B^{\beta\alpha\mu} \\
g_{\gamma\alpha}A^{\alpha\beta\mu} &= g_{\gamma\alpha}B^{\beta\alpha\mu} \\
A_{\gamma}^{\ \ \beta\mu} &= B_{\ \ \gamma}^{\beta\ \ \mu}
\end{align}$$
and then you can relabel $\gamma\to\alpha$ in the whole expression.

You can use this same general procedure to show that
$$m^{\alpha\beta} = -m^{\beta\alpha} \Longleftrightarrow m_{\alpha\beta} = -m_{\beta\alpha}$$